# Vb.net Try Finally (no catch)

Tags: .net, vb.net, try-catch

Quiz question: **What is the output of running the following program:**

```
 Sub Main()
      Try
         CallToMethodThatThrowsException()
      Catch ex As ArgumentException
         Console.WriteLine("Argument exception caught")
      Finally
         Console.WriteLine("Outer finally block")
      End Try
   End Sub

   Public Sub CallToMethodThatThrowsException()
      Try
         ThrowExceptionMethod()
      Finally
         Console.WriteLine("Inner finally block")
      End Try
   End Sub

   Public Sub ThrowExceptionMethod()
      Throw New ArgumentException()
   End Sub
```

No code writing please :) - the first to answer correctly gets the **big prize** (an accepted answer :) )

Comment: Haha, what kind of question is this? You already know the answer because (presumably) you've tested it yourself. What are you actually curious to know? Anything?

Comment: You ought to accept the first answer with the correct sequence (@Pieter's) or one that is correct in every detail (none - the output will not have quotes around the text and be correctly cased).

Comment: Well, the answer did not come to me naturally and I thought having it somewhere black-on-white could be useful.

Comment: I accepted the first answer with the correct sequence - the logic was what interested me, not the quotes/spelling

Comment: except you accepted by the order in which it appeared in the list, not the order in which it was created. Note that the default ordering is not by date/time, but by votes, then random if the number of votes is the same. A particularly confusing feature which many have complained about, but which is stubbornly clung to by the management. @Pieter's answer came at ~14:55 UTC and @Ben's came almost 2 minutes later at ~14:57 UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Inner finally block"
"Argument exception caught"
"Outer finally block"

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume:
inner finally block
argument exception caught
outer finally block